# JavaScript cancel event on input type data with ng-change

Tags: javascript, date, input

I use angular I have this

I want that soSome() cancel the enter of data if he want
however I have been proved with (e.preventDefault, e.stopPropagation, return false) like this

```
$scope.doSome(event){event.stopPropagation();return false}
```

I also prove this

```
$('#dateInput').on('change',(event)=>{console.log(event);window.event.stopPropagation();window.event.cancelBubble = true;return false;});
```

to try that don't allow modified never for example but doesn't work nothing
in this case event was set and I could see in the console.log.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

That is a jQuery event. If you want to use ngChange you would do something like this:

controller.js

```
$scope.doSomething = function(event){
 console.log('hello')
 event.stopPropagation()
};
```

html_file.html

```
<div id="dateInput" ng-change="doSomething($event)"></div>
```

Suggest you also take a look at the ngChange documentation
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: where is the event cancel ? I already prove in $scope.doSomething with return with event.cancel even $event.cancel, plus the code Jquery.

Comment: Updated the code so i take the event parameter if that is what you want, don't understand completely what the problem you have

Comment: Your new updated code doesn't work same way didn't work to me when I used a long time ago I alredy said that I proved with $scope.doSomeThing and event.stopPropagation() maybe in description of post seems that I just prove with Jquery but I probe with $scope too.